# How do I deploy a huge NDJSON file into a cluster for distributed computation and storage? (DARPA TC Engagement 5 Theai)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, dataset, cluster-computing, ndjson

I am a data scientist with the task of anomaly detection on system logs and I want to experiment on the DARPA TC Engagement 5 dataset.
I have downloaded the included scripts to import the data and now the data is being parsed and stored in a single huge `ndjson` file.

**What's my end goal?**

Use `PySpark` for distributed computation and storage of the huge `ndjson` file on the cluster (so I can delete the `ndjson` and then only use the distributed data).

**What's my issue?**

Due to my lack of experience with newly deployed data, I dont know how to deploy the data on the cluster, I was thinking to just read the huge file using `PySpark`, repartition it and save as parquet but that seems very basic and inefficient.

**What else do I need? (nice to have) (TC Engagement 5 dataset)**

While optional, It would be nice to know of a better way to decompress and parse the DARPA TC Engagement 5 dataset (Theai in this case), the included `JAR` parse the data and stream it into an `elasticsearch` service, since I dont have one I have to modify the `Java class` responsible to stream it to a local file instead (on the cluster), There must be a better and faster way to do that.

Thanks in advance for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: I just want to add that the package `fastavro` is useful when dealing with DARPA dataset for parsing and decompressing.